# how can I active my program with a special key?

Tags: java

I write a program with java now i want when press special key(or click) my program go to system tray.

and when i press a special key it actives.

please show me some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Component and have Keyboard events associated to it. See the sample code on how to minimize the application to System tray.

You can see the sample code [here.](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/2296-minimize-system-tray-windows.html)